# How to view the total unqiue values for each cloumns if total unique value is less than a specific no. in my dataset

Tags: pandas

i am working on Heart Disease Prediction data and i want to know the unqiue values for each column

first i took total unique feature in my data is

```
framinghamDF.nunique()

output-

male                  2
age                  39
education             4
currentSmoker         2
cigsPerDay           33
BPMeds                2
prevalentStroke       2
prevalentHyp          2
diabetes              2
totChol             248
sysBP               234
diaBP               146
BMI                1364
heartRate            73
glucose             143
TenYearCHD            2
dtype: int64
```

now i took out individual features unique values

```
print(framinghamDF["education"].unique().tolist())
output
[4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, nan]
```

but i want to get all unique values of features which has less than 4 unique values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter index values of `Series` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = framinghamDF.nunique()

out = s.index[s < 4].tolist()
#alternative
out = s[s < 4].index.tolist()
```

Last for all unique values use:

```
d = {x: framinghamDF[x].unique() for x in out}
```

Comment: i want output for those unique values not the features which are having unique values less than 4
like i did it for this column which results the total unique value available for this feature 
print(framinghamDF["education"].unique().tolist())

can it be done on multiple features 

print(framinghamDF[["education","currentSmoker"]].unique().tolist())

when i am trying for multiple columns it is giving error

Comment: @Anubhav - So how should looks expected output?

Comment: i want to know all the unqiue values for each feature.
i tried it for single value -

print(framinghamDF["education"].unique().tolist())

but when i am trying it for multiple columns it is not happening -

print(framinghamDF[["education","currentSmoker"]].unique().tolist())

Comment: Like `d = {x: framinghamDF[x].unique() for x in out}`  after my solution ?

Comment: yes i got the output which i want now, thanks for your help.
i am a beginner to python, can you explain this code as per my understanding you made a dictionary here in which each element is the column with its values which fits the condition we gave earlier.